# Command pattern how to solve issue with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a concrete button class:

```
class ContourButton implements Button {
    public icon: string;
    public title: string;

    constructor(public command: Command) {
    }
}
```

This button accepts a command that should be executed after click.

**Command looks like:**

```
export class ContourCommand implements Command {
    constructor(public action: EditAction) {}

    undo(): void {
        this.action.undo();
    }
    redo(): void {
        // TODO
    }
    execute(): void {
        this.action.execute();
    }

    complete(): void {
        this.action.complete();
    }
}
```

This class gives a **reciever** as `public action: EditAction` that contains business logic.

Also there is a **manager of commands** which adds a command to stack:

```
class CommandManager {
    public currentCommand: Command;
    protected commands: Command[] = [];
    protected undoCommand: Command;

    execute(command: Command): void {
        if (command === this.currentCommand) return;
        this.currentCommand = command;
        this.commands.push(this.currentCommand);
        this.currentCommand.execute();
    }
}
```

I dislike this line of code:

```
 const command = new ContourCommand(new EditorManager(new Type()));
 const button1 = new ContourButton(command);
 const button2 = new PinButton(command);

 const buttons = [button1, button2];
```

**Template is:**

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="btnClick($event)"></div>
```

**Handle click:**

```
public btnClick(button: Button) {
    this.commandManager.execute(button.command);
}
```

Because to create a command I need to specify a reciever entity as `new EditorManager()` that has own dependencies.

Do I use this pattern properly and how to solve this side effect with dependencies? I write this as library, so I dont have any DI mechanism here.

Comment: I don’t understand why ContourButton is creating a new command at all.  It is already requiring a command as an argument!  Is seems like the like that you dislike can be deleted entirely.

Comment: Sorry it is typo, I fixed it

Comment: Additionally your CommandManager class can be cleaned up.  Isn’t this.currentCommand just that last item in the this.commands array? If commands are undoable and redouble (such that the current isn’t always the last) then the information that you want to know is the current index in the array.  The currentCommand can be derived from that like this.commands[this.currentIndex].

Comment: Yes, but I need to encapsultate commans: [] somewhere in class. That is why commandManagerExist. Or do you mean I dont need variable `currentCommand: Command;`?

Comment: ContourCommand doesn’t do anything?  Or did you remove the logic to make this more of a minimal example?  It just wraps an EditAction which is already executable.  So you could pass the EditorManager to the Button directly.

Comment: `ContourCommand` deligates call to `public action: EditAction` inside execute method.

Comment: I did not get this: `So you could pass the EditorManager to the Button directly. `

Comment: Yes I mean you don’t need that variable. You could use a get accessor to make it a public readonly property like get currentCommand(): Command | undefined { return this.commands[this.currentIndex] } but I’m not sure that you want it be accessible from outside the CommandManager.

Comment: EditorManager implements EditAction and EditAction has methods execute(), undo(), complete().  So EditAction implements Command, no?  So you could call  new Button( new EditorManager( new Type() ) ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231256/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-jessy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Command Manager

You and I worked on this code together in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231256/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-jessy) for quite a long time.  We realized that the "job" of the `CommandManager` is to manage the stack of actions for the purpose of `undo()` and `redo()` operations.

The `CommandManager` should store the `index` of the current action.  We increment the index when adding or redoing actions and decrement when undoing.  When a new action is added after some have been undone, we need to remove all redoable "future" commands.  The new command needs to be at the correct index and also needs to be the top item in the stack.

Rather than executing an action through the `CommandManager`, your individual objects are executing some operation themselves based on user events.  They then "register" this action to the `CommandManager` and provide `undo()` and `redo()` methods.  Those methods are closures based on the arguments of the original operation.  In simple terms, if an object has a `value` of 5 and calls `setValue(10)`, then it would send this operation to the `CommandManager` as `{undo: () => setValue(5), redo: () => setValue(10)}`.

---

We could make this compatible with a more traditional Command Pattern design if we define a `Command` as something with an `execute()` method that returns the `undo()` and `redo()` functions.

```
interface RegisteredAction {
  undo(): void;
  redo(): void;
}

interface Command {
    execute(): RegisteredAction;
}

export class CommandManager {
  protected commands: RegisteredAction[] = [];
  protected currentIndex = -1;

  // add a command to the stack which was executed elsewhere
  didExecute(command: RegisteredAction): void {
    this.currentIndex++;
    this.commands.splice(this.currentIndex, this.commands.length, command);
  }

  // trigger execution of a command from here
  execute(command: Command): void {
      const action = command.execute();
      this.didExecute(action);
  }

  // the command to undo
  get currentCommand(): RegisteredAction | undefined {
    return this.commands[this.currentIndex];
  }

   // the command to redo
  get nextCommand(): RegisteredAction | undefined {
    return this.commands[this.currentIndex + 1];
  }

  // whether on not the current stack can be undone
  get canUndo(): boolean {
    return !!this.currentCommand;
  }

  // whether on not the current stack supports redo
  get canRedo(): boolean {
    return !!this.nextCommand;
  }

  // undo one command, if possible
  // could potentially return a boolean that indicates if an undo occurred
  undo(): void {
    if (this.currentCommand) {
      this.currentCommand.undo();
      this.currentIndex--;
    }
  }

  // redo one command, if possible
  redo(): void {
    if (this.nextCommand) {
      this.nextCommand.redo();
      this.currentIndex++;
    }
  }

  // undo all commands
  cancel(): void {
    while (this.currentIndex >= 0) {
      this.undo();
    }
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQObAM6ShAEwEEExgB7EZAbwChlkBXEA8gCgEoAuZAN3OAEA3PWT5WnHv0EiAvrVqg88JMgDC5ALaa4LGqIYQAHhASNIktJhx5CJMpTkKEAGzjZs6rTpYBZXXAY0PoMAA5Q5JCkhMgI3roE2DzoWLjQdqQUIADaALrIALzIeSJhEVGQBLGMUPjgAJIsxoXIALQAjCKiAPTdyHAEVXCx8Xpg5MhgABYouIgA1sgA7lPACFPL7sjGpuYxEC7YECvpogSCAKImZhZx2gnJ1mni9lncfAJVdAwM0zgAdGZahAGk0jABqcGlH5-bCA0aJf7YUIuNYQNiwwE1OpgRoEYwAGkmqzhdx8iJcIIw0yJZISHGh8h6fTAUGAGCCUG213MWWQ5Bg-RG9z0MAimmQM3woh2N3RdJYPA0IoI72kXwMPziIFw-UylBaCoI-1le040J%20xIB5wIV12FkQDhADNETIYvWJKCNkwmzFYoiCYGqwPAyvJlhSNnSxH1VAAPkwmjBQDFvj98GAalRMUbsNkc9iQbiwblGQofh7pl6ET6xIRyAGIEGQMYwGGEhGnrYY07kAm-RBky2NZaM1mraSEXmCyHi-ijMhwch2qXXeXkB6TlWuQaQJFPcGccg5ghFghdMgAEYoP2UCCNoPnkAAVRY7Hel-I5EpF7TDDHUBUAAhEBM44u2LBlsyywzNu-JUHuQZVoeRbHmACzHowoShOQUBgJ44gNgwgaxLo6ASB%20X4-lQf51pmgHICBmItkYbYIlB7p9Le8HViqRLAIKOEeMAl6UtBcSMC4VQ4ZA4DAHALguAAnnR47DJ%2034QBe0xwEGoDnOekCeAJ-RUNx5AIEC4iiLeljqiEPwmRiJJYrOEGqg5lpgUW7n-LZLqWr8LlWUWeLGK0rQWsg8gMG6G59IRPHCuS-GCeQwmife-71nZnyecgTnMa27kcPlQUAixbEqv8hHmpq5WkoWoLzpCUUxdF64etxCkuMlCTYKIT5IC4uWCPlKzAJSyDOQCIXNc0AB8RQAAylbRDV%20W%20dWWu18hMq47ieAAMuQHLQO5BWaCiECaEWngXbR2q4FAjCkLhbChIwolrMgIBwLdPDPaAGBre1DCaqaFhrfVWqUNgmn-C4p1sAARLKmaVMgKOLhO-x-bdAWBdl9E0TDRO3jwnCFAtIw6gjSMYKj3HY0uzH-RAHAEmTgWEZTpUFDTT308jKOJSzuP4xz3Ngx1%201w0GPiBMERQtksXgqv4f2cnViuciaPIWKryAnWdUDuajRAoxwLq69A%20v2uiRsm5y5sowAQlbNsBHrkOO8cxunS7CKo2onsiLbUCbRRQjxYmrDqLQEdR%20%20MddW%20yBu4n3t27VDKx4lmdJ77bBO4H53ByjAAiYdZ1rdtDQc5pAA)

---

### Buttons

You had initially thought that every button in your application would be tied to a `Command`.  In reality our "Undo" and "Redo" buttons will be tied to the `CommandManager`.  We included `canUndo` and `canRedo` properties in the `CommandManager` so that we can know the `disabled` state of those buttons.

```
export interface Button {
  icon: string;
  title: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  onClick(): void;
}

class UndoButton implements Button {
  icon = "undoicon"; //placeholder
  title = "Undo";
  constructor(private manager: CommandManager) {}

  onClick() {
    this.manager.undo();
  }

  get disabled() {
    return !this.manager.canUndo;
  }
}

class RedoButton implements Button {
  icon = "redoicon"; //placeholder
  title = "Redo";
  constructor(private manager: CommandManager) {}

  onClick() {
    this.manager.redo();
  }

  get disabled() {
    return !this.manager.canRedo;
  }
}
```